# Training classifier on randomly generated negative samples

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, recommender-system, similarities

I have $M$ (~dozen million) feature vectors. There are $F$ (~several dozen thousand) binary features, but in each vector, only $H$ (~several hundred) of them would be 1, the rest are 0.

Now, for a given subset of $M$, let's call it $S1$ (~several dozen thousand vectors) I have to find another subset of $M$ let's say $S2$ that fulfils the following criteria:

1. vectors from $S2$ have 'similar characteristics' (features) as vectors from $S1$. (I am not interested in only distance metric like Jaccard, but underlying pattern of features).

   - It is assumed that vectors from subset $S1$ have characteristics that significantly distinguish them from other vectors in $M$. However, still, there are other vectors in $M$ that have some affinities to $S1$.
2. $S1$$\cap$$S2$=$\emptyset$ (intersection is zero)
3. $\big|S1\big|$ $\approx$ $10\big|S2\big|$ (ten times more elements)
4. $F(N)$ $\approx$ $S1$$\cup$$S2$ (find function $F$ that selects only
   'right' elements from $M$)

***Possible Solution***: Train classification model (find $F$) on vectors from the set $S1$ (class 1) and randomly generated vectors (class 0). Then, feed the model with all vectors ($F(M)$) and check for probabilities of belonging to class 1. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may, or may not work, you could try it, but I wouldn't expect much of it. It may give different results depending on the nature of your data, but consider an example where the data are images, the "random" data would be just white noise images looking like the one below. *Whatever* real-life image you would take, it would differ from the "random" image, because it would have all sorts of patterns in it.

[image]

So if you train a classifier on it, it would likely learn to distinguish your pictures from the random ones, but this would not help you anyhow with solving any real life problems.

For such highly imbalanced data, you could try useing anomaly detection algorithms (e.g. [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification)), or [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning), that will learn to tag the minority class within some unlabelled data (if you have any).